# Why get different answer between tan(pi) on calculator?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

The `tan(pi)` is `0`, but When I calculate `tan(math.pi)` with Python. Answer is `-1.2246467991473532e-16`.

I can't comprehend.

Comment: It's closer to zero than `math.pi` is to pi...

Comment: You can't program without understanding how IEEE floating point numbers work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python answer is equal to zero to 10 significant digits.

```
-0.00000000000000012246467991473532
 xxxxxxxxxxxyyy
```

Calculators tend to use about 13 digits internally for their calculations, but only 10 for display. Either way, this value is 0 by the calculator's standards.

Comment: Single precision IEEE floating point numbers have 7 digits of precision; double precision numbers have 16 digits.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score 6):

`e-16` means `* 10^-16`, quite close to zero (not perfectly, partly because `pi` was not perfect). On the calculator, it is just rounded to zero.